# How can I access the return data from a Facebook dialog on my site?

Tags: facebook

I'm using a [Facebook request dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) in my app.

```
FB.init({
    appId  : 'app_id',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});

$('.facebook_request').live('click',function(){ 
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'message',
        to: 'user_id'
    });
    return false;
});
```

This works so far. The request pops up in the current page, and it gets created correctly. But I'm not sure how to access the return data (`id` of the newly created request) as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). How can I get access to it so I can save the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request_id` comes back in a callback:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'message',
    to: 'user_id'
}, function(response)
{
    for (i = 0; i < response.request_ids.length; i++)
    {
        alert(response.request_ids[i]);
    }
});
```